# Keras: Why is loss different for train_on_batch() and test_on_batch() when same input is being passed to both functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am passing the same input i.e same data and same true labels to keras train_on_batch() and test_on_batch(). I want to know why I am getting different loss values for both functions.

**code:**

```
model_del_fin.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.001,decay=0.001/15), loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
iters_per_epoch = 1285 // 50
print(iters_per_epoch)
num_epochs = 15
outs_store_freq = 20 # in iters
print_loss_freq = 20 # in iters

iter_num = 0
epoch_num = 0
model_outputs = []
loss_history  = []

while epoch_num < num_epochs:
  print("ok")
  while iter_num < iters_per_epoch:
    x_train, y_train = next(train_it2)
    loss_history += [model_del_fin.train_on_batch([x_train,x_train], y_train)]
    print("Iter {} loss: {}".format(iter_num, loss_history[-1]))
    print(model_del_fin.test_on_batch([x_train,x_train], y_train))
    iter_num += 1
  print("EPOCH {} FINISHED".format(epoch_num + 1))

  epoch_num += 1
  iter_num = 0 # reset counter
```

**Result: **

> > Iter 0 loss: [5.860205, 0.24]  [2.5426426, 0.68] 
> >      Iter 1 loss: [3.5718067, 0.48]  [1.7102847, 0.68]  Iter 2 loss: [2.0221999, 0.68]
> >     [1.310905, 0.94]  Iter 3 loss: [1.6114614, 0.74] [1.2987132, 0.92]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem stems from feeding data to a model in *train mode* vs. *inference mode*; differences include:

- **Train mode**: `Dropout` is active, `BatchNormalization` uses *batch* statistics for mean & variance
- **Inference**: all `Dropout` rates are set to zero, and `BatchNormalization` uses *exponential moving average* statistics for mean & variance, computed during training

Other diffferences also apply. Assuming models used in your code are based on those in other question(s) (i.e. VGG) - it'll be the BN layers. As a workaround, you can temporarily set a global learning phase via:

```py
K.set_learning_phase(0) # INFERENCE MODE
K.set_learning_phase(1) # TRAIN MODE
```

Note, however, that either of these must be executed *before* the model is instantiated, else changes will not apply. Also, this may not solve the problem entirely, as BN is known to have [other issues](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12400) (which I happen to be currently investigating) - but results should agree a lot closer nonetheless.

Lastly, if you *first* call `train_on_batch()` and *then* call `test_on_batch()`, the two will disagree because `test` executes after `train` has updated weights - thus, call `test_on_batch()` first, *then* `train_on_batch()`.

---

**Full example**:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

K.set_learning_phase(0)

ipt = Input((12,))
x   = Dropout(0.1)(ipt)
out = Dense(12)(x)

model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
X = np.random.randn(32, 12)

print(model.train_on_batch(X, X))
print(model.test_on_batch(X, X))
print(model.train_on_batch(X, X))
```

```py
2.1212778 # train_on_batch()
2.1128066 # test_on_batch()
2.1128066 # train_on_batch()
```

Try using `K.set_learning_phase(1)` instead to see the difference - or comment it out entirely, as `1` is the default value anyway.